# Real power and power factor for resonant RLC parallel circuit

Tags: parallel, power-factor-correction, resonant-converter

I have no problem finding parts a, b and c, however I don't know how to get part d. You don't have to solve it for me(although it'd be greatly appreciated), but please give me somewhat of a hint or a formula to figure out the answer. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: where is the resistor in the circuit - parallel with C or in series with L?

Comment: sound like this question is homework.

Comment: @roh why do you care where it's coming from? if you can't answer, why are you commenting?

Comment: @ShidehNaderi I guess you thought that I down-voted your question, is it correct? I didn't down-vote your question.

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework.

Comment: @ShidehNaderi People here are happy to help people understand what is required to solve home-work problems and assignments BUT there is general agreement not to actually do the work for those who inquire, and this is a common position taken by many similar groups. Helping beginners to help themselves is an important aim. So Roh is correct to comment and Matt is a bit brief in his comment but somewhat correct.

Comment: @roh No, I didn't think you did it, and frankly it doesn't matter who did it.

Comment: @MattYoung It's final's week, and that's a final's practice exam question that I had trouble solving. It'd be nice if people made a better use of themselves,rather than just repeating the good old "We're not here to do your homework!". As you can see, I clearly stated that I don't want you to solve it for me, I asked for a hint. If I wanted plain solution, I would have posted this question on Chegg! If you want to make this an 'experts only' community, then simply deny access to public.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I understand. In my reply to Matt, I stated that this is a final's practice exam question and in my question, I said I don't want you to solve it for me, I need a hint or a formula to figure it out. But the issue is responders are becoming more and more selective on here and on stackoverflow. It's starting to look like this is turning into an experts only community, where experts ask other experts questions and if you're not an expert and need help, no matter if you've put effort into solving something, you'd be accused of asking people to do your homework.

Comment: @ShidehNaderi - More selective - yes, unfortunately. But with an expert bias - less so. I feel the need to spend an excessive amount of effort railing against question closures where the question seems entirely reasonable. This seems like an example - although for different reasons than most.

Comment: Rusty. ... looks ... . Is not max Power jut resistive power = V^2/R. You have calculated R in (b) [presumably from Q = L/R or whatever.]  Power at half power points is half this (where am I going wrong? :-) ). From whence power factor should be not too hard (reactive component, real  component, angle ... .  ||
[Possibly useful?](http://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/materials/StudyGuide/guide12.pdf) ||| and [even maybe wikipedia?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit) |||  [Maybe](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/serres.html)

Comment: and [Looks good](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=tB7qB2xQL28C&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306&dq=resonant+circuit+power+delivered+at+half+power+frequencies&source=bl&ots=sVfQmPXJ1E&sig=Wj0XwFMbsH1BhByjc5dhwDoc4dA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qUVvU7CZNcfPkgXU7IEY&ved=0CG8Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=resonant%20circuit%20power%20delivered%20at%20half%20power%20frequencies&f=false). At a venture - my system decides to not open PPTs for some reason so ...

Comment: [Thusly](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.eecs.utk.edu%2F~green%2Fnotes%2FResonant%2520Circuits.ppt&ei=qUVvU7CZNcfPkgXU7IEY&usg=AFQjCNE-X2K0DEVVToKwIqCovLSU8lLubg&sig2=QsPJusAtYcdmpA-LKI0fCQ&bvm=bv.66330100,d.dGI&cad=rja) ||| [and also](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopencourses.emu.edu.tr%2Fmod%2Fresource%2Fview.php%3Fid%3D155%26redirect%3D1&ei=qUVvU7CZNcfPkgXU7IEY&usg=AFQjCNHchjUm0zVqrcZyTFnnnnNHLtc1vA&sig2=oeNh_R4SVXe6AG98PGgx1A&bvm=bv.66330100,d.dGI&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to get part d

If R, L and C are in parallel then the real power delivered by the source is: -

\$\dfrac{V^2}{R}\$ (irrespective of frequency and the values of L and C).

Because you say you can find answers to (a), (b) and (c), then you know the value of the resistor that is in parallel with L and C from (b).

For the 2nd question in part (d) you need to work out what current is flowing into the LC part . At resonance, this current is zero but at the 3dB points it isn't - at frequencies below perfect resonance the current is dominated by the inductance and, above resonance it is dominated by capacitance.

So, you know the 3dB points (half power points) from (c) and you know L and C therefore you can calculate current into L and current into C. For instance, (a) tells you that resonance is: -

\$\omega_0 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$ = 25,000 rad/sec (3979 Hz)

You can calculate the 3dB points knowing that Q = resonant frequency divided by bandwidth; therefore bandwidth is 25,000/1000 = 25 radians/sec and, 3dB points are half of this - you now have 3dB points at 24,987.5 rad/sec and 25,012.5 rad/sec.

So, work out \$X_L\$ and \$X_C\$ at these 3dB points, calculate the current for both cases (don't forget that one is of the opposite sign) and now you have the reactive currents at each 3dB point.

Find the phase angle between resistive and reactive currents use Tan\$^{-1}\$(ratio) and take the cosine to yield power factor.